# Backbone.js: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'set'

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I encountered the error I tried to use the reset method on one of my view's collection.

Here is its implementation

The collection:

```
window.Cards = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Card,
    url: "/cards"
});
```

The router file:

```
var cardsList = new Cards();
cardsList.fetch({success: function(){
    filteredCards = cardsList.where({Class: "ABC"}).concat(cardsList.where({Class: "ZYX"}));
    this.deckbuild = new Deckbuilder({collection:filteredCards});
}});
```

In my Deckbuilder view file I created another view within it using the same collection:

```
var cardselectView = new CardSelect({collection: this.collection});
```

Then in the CardSelect view file I wrote:

```
blahblah = new Collection();
this.collection.set(blahblah);
```

Then the error appeared. Is there anything wrong this my implementation? Did I violate some abstraction? I can no longer use any of Backbone's collection method on my collection object anymore.

Comment: `where`, `findWhere` and bunch of methods return array not an instance of `Backbone.Collection` Please refer back to `Backbone` doc… http://backbonejs.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the router file, collection passed to the `Deckbuilder` view is an array and not `Backbone.Collection`. Try making below change :

```
this.deckbuild = new Deckbuilder({collection: new Cards(filteredCards)});
```